# class array default setting c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, default-value

I can't find any information on whether or not you can set default values for arrays created via a class and/or any syntax for arrays made via classes beyond mere creation. Please help.

```
// strings
#include <string> 

//normal setup
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

// multi array setup
class recordtype { 
public: 
    // array vars
    string namef; 
    string namel;
    char size; 
}; 
// array 
recordtype listof[11];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [value-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) all of the elements of the array using this syntax, eg:

```cpp
recordtype listof[11]();
```

Which, in your example, will default-construct all of the `string` fields, and set all of the `char` fields to 0.

Though, in this case, it would be better to give `recordtype` a default constructor to initialize its members as needed, and then let the `recordtype listof[11];` syntax call that constructor on each element for you.

Otherwise, you can specify actual values for specific elements, eg:

```cpp
recordtype listof[11]{ // or: = {
    {"name1", "name2", 'A'},
    {"name1", "name2", 'B'},
    // and so on...
};
```

In this case, any array element(s) that are not explicitly initialized will be value-initialized.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/vQQqDj), exactly as I wrote it